# Xpath to extract from following siblings until the next specified node

Tags: xpath, import.io

I'm trying to extract everything from the `p` nodes that follow the `h2` containing `"Summary"` until I get to the next `h2`.

This is what I have so far:

`.//h2[contains(text(),'Summary')]/following-sibling::*`

I just don't know how to get it to stop. Is this even possible?

[image: html]

Comment: add  p[1] instead of the last * .If you have multiple h2 elements with text Summary then add [1] after [contains(..)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you select `p[preceding-sibling::h2[1][contains(., 'Summary')]` you will select all `p` children of the context node which have (the or a) `h2` containing `Summary` as the immediately preceding `h2` sibling.

If you want all such elements (e.g. the `ul` too) then use `*[not(self::h2)][preceding-sibling::h2[1][contains(., 'Summary')]`.

Or you could try `.//h2[contains(., 'Summary')]/following-sibling::*[preceding-sibling::h2[1][contains(., 'Summary')]]`.

Comment: This is great thanks very much .//p[preceding-sibling::h2[1][contains(., 'Summary')]] works perfectly. I hadn't considered working 'backwards'.